# How to make git-config to use spaces instead of tabs

Tags: git

When I use git-config to edit my .gitconfig file, it inserts tabs. Is there a way to make it insert spaces instead of tabs?

(The motivation is that when I hand-edit the file, I always insert spaces. Git's use of tabs makes the file inconsistent. Of course I could just use tabs myself, but that's just ridiculous.)

Comment: Umm... git-config isn't an editor. It just opens up your text editor program (vim/ gedit/etc)

Comment: @Chris You can use `git config` to modify your `.gitconfig` file programmatically though, and it will use tabs when adding new lines to the configuration.  I think this is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: I see from looking at the source code for Git [line #1776 of the most recent config.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/config.c#L1776), it looks like Git always wants to use a tab.  You could of course edit this file and recompile Git itself --- at least for your local installation.

Comment: Good question, I don't know why nobody upvoted it. @Wolf That's a good answer, why not put it as an answer post?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was answered above in a comment by @Wolf, but to reiterate: this is hard-coded in Git's [`write_pair`](https://github.com/git/git/blame/a38d39a4c50d1275833aba54c4dbdfce9e2e9ca1/config.c#L3031) (formerly [`store_write_pair`](https://github.com/git/git/blame/80ba04ed9b07c34af9cc644f2183b3b80fd81744/config.c#L1918-L1919)) implementation, which was most recently refactored in [2017](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9bd4cbb9cce9f872cc4427d1c27a62c6768b12a) and originally implemented in [2005](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10bea152a34b2bf1194ede5e0c9e5595ab2100f3).

Comment: tip: In Sept 2017, [d9bd4cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9bd4cbb9cce9f872cc4427d1c27a62c6768b12a) renamed `store_write_pair()` to `write_pair()`. This change is effective since v2.14.3.