# Can git be told to use spaces in ~/.gitconfig?

Tags: git, indentation, spaces

When I use `git config --global <some option> <some value>`, Git will write the relevant entry in my `~/.gitconfig`, indented by one **tab**. Since [my `~/.gitconfig`](https://github.com/raxod502/radian/blob/master/.gitconfig) is version-controlled and I want it to not be a mess, I then have to go in by hand and replace the tab with spaces.

Can Git be told to use spaces automatically when adding entries to `~/.gitconfig`?

(Please note that this is **not** about the indentation in the code that I'm *committing* with Git, but rather the indentation in Git's own configuration file.)

Comment: what is wrong with tab?

Comment: also, why is your personal `~/.gitconfig` published to SCM?  is your entire home (`~`) directory under version control? am i missing something?

Comment: There's no real real config option to tell "git config" to use tabs instead of spaces but since you did mention that your .gitconfig is part of the repo, you could set a filter to your .gitconfig with clean option to unexpand and then gitattribute to to use that filter.. if you need example, i'll write one down - otherwise, just use google and land here: https://alexzaytsev.me/2014/10/19/git-filter-to-convert-spaces-to-tabs-and-vice-versa/

Comment: @David: Whatever my personal feelings are on the matter, spaces are the *de facto* standard for indentation in most types of files. My [dotfiles repository](https://github.com/raxod502/radian) contains a number of different file types, and I wish to be consistent in using spaces for all of them.

Comment: @sircapsalot It's extremely common to publish collections of dotfiles to e.g. Github. This is what I have done. One of my dotfiles is `~/.gitconfig`; it is included because it contains many useful aliases that other people might be interested in. You can see the entire repository [here](https://github.com/raxod502/radian).

Comment: @rasjani: I do not want tabs in the copy of [my dotfiles repository](https://github.com/raxod502/radian) that is pushed to Github, and I do not want tabs in my working directory. In fact, I do not want any tabs, anywhere, ever. That's why I don't think filters are an adequate solution to this problem (but if I have misunderstood their purpose, please correct me).

Comment: @RadonRosborough, IMO there's nothing wrong with using spaces in some files and tabs in others if they're different types of files. For example, I would never use tabs in Python source because of PEP-8, and I would always use tabs in Makefiles because they're required. What is wrong with doing that? Just make sure to be consistent within each type of files within each project. (Having said that, I'm not aware of any good answer to your question. I would like to see one, and have upvoted your question.)

Comment: Wow, the above discussion is very reminiscent of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsoOG6ZeyUI

Comment: @AshutoshJindal ;) Personally, I actually prefer tabs. But I like to be consistent, and every project I've ever worked on has used spaces, so…

Comment: I don't understand why the keys are indented at all?  Anyone know?  Then the indent char would be moot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32186600/1959808

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what worked for me (note that as @rasjani has pointed out in a comment, there is no option to *prevent* git from inserting a tab in the first place when using `git config`.)

---

#### Create the filter

Create a `filter` to convert tabs to spaces automatically as soon as you do a `git add` for a file. This filter is created by

```
git config --global filter.spacify.clean 'expand --tabs=4 --initial'
```

*The `expand` command says that `convert each tab character at the beginning of line to 4 space characters`*

Therefore the definition of the filter includes both *what* it does and for *when* it does it (i.e. for which git operation).

(On OSX, you would need to use `gexpand` *after* installing coreutils by doing a `brew install coreutils`)

Of course, you would need to decide the [scope](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) (`--system`, `--global` or the default `--local`) of the above configuration.

---

#### Specify the files/path patterns to which the filter will be applied

For instance, for your [repository](https://github.com/raxod502/radian), create a `.git/info/attributes` with the following content:

```
.* filter=spacify
```

This says that *`apply the spacify filter to any files that match the pattern .*` before these files are committed to the repository.*

---

Note that the above will only affect new files being added to the repository. If you want this to be done for all existing files, then you could either run `expand` manually OR, could get git to do it for us like so:

```
git config --global filter.spacify.smudge 'expand --tabs=4 --initial'
git checkout HEAD -- **
```

Using the `spacify` filter for `smudge` will cause the filter to be applied to files being checked out. After the checkout, you should see a bunch of changes to the dot files which had leading tabs converted to spaces. Re-commit these and from henceforth, the `smudge` and `clean` duo shall keep your dotfiles tab-free!

---

#### Update -- The pull request!

Here is a pull request for your repo : https://github.com/raxod502/radian/pull/156

Comment: While this solution helps, I'd like to prevent Git from inserting tabs in the first place. For instance, the last command you give (`git config --global filter.spacify.smudge ...`) will *itself* insert a tab into my `.gitconfig`!

Comment: But that tab won't end up in your repository since as soon as you commit the changed `.gitconfig` , the `spacify` filter will do it's black magic. I have updated my answer to emphasize the fact that at the time of this writing, there doesn't appear to be an option to force git to use spaces instead of tabs for `git config`.

Comment: Well, that makes me sad. I'll accept this answer since it is the next best thing for someone who wants to use spaces.

Comment: I think you should add a note that using this filter without preventing it from changing certain files, such as Makefile, will cause them many headaches. Makefiles will error and not run if you use spaces.